# Pyomo takes so long to solve model

Tags: python, pyomo

I have almost very simple model with several constraints as you can see. You can see the comments for each variable also. How can I improve the performance of pyomo solver ?

```
from pyomo.environ import *

wh = ConcreteModel()

#p - material name (str)
#r - shelf name (str)
#d - number of material pallets that will be placed in one month (int)
#a - number of superimposed material pallets for each shelf (int) 
#b - occupy rate of each single material pallet for each shelf (float-between 0-1) 

wh.x=Var(p,r,within=NonNegativeIntegers)

wh.value = Objective(
expr = sum( a[i,j]*wh.x[i,j] for i in p for j in r),
sense = maximize )

def const1_rule(wh,j):
    return sum(wh.x[i,j]*b[i,j] for i in p)<=1
wh.const1=Constraint(r,rule=const1_rule)

def const2_rule(wh,i):
    return sum(wh.x[i,j]*a[i,j] for j in r)<=d[i]
wh.const2=Constraint(p,rule=const2_rule)

opt=SolverFactory('glpk')
result_obj=opt.solve(wh,tee=True)

wh.pprint()
```

Comment: Since the code is incomplete, I cannot run the code.

Comment: What are the decision variables? What are the known and unknown?

Comment: What does "superimposed material pallets" mean?

Comment: What are the bounds of the variables?

Comment: Hello @QuriousCube, sorry I'm kinda newbie so is there any proper way to share all the codes with you ? Superimposed pallet means stacked up pallets. Pallets could be stacked vertically on top of each other on shelves. I hope it is understandable now.  All p,r,d,a,b values are comes calculated from the main code block. Since there are many options, I need to find best solution with these variables.